# Failure during offline execution of com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:1.4.0:dockerBuild plugin

Tags: java, maven, docker, maven-plugin, jib

How should I set up this maven plugin when there is no access to the online docker registry to force use local resources only?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:1.4.0:dockerBuild (default-cli) on project mental: registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution: Unknown host registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution -> [Help 1]
```

the plugin conf is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <from>
            <image>adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot</image>
        </from>
        <to>
            <image>mental:latest</image>
        </to>
        <container>
            <entrypoint>
                <shell>sh</shell>
                <option>-c</option>
                <arg>chmod +x /entrypoint.sh &amp;&amp; sync &amp;&amp; /entrypoint.sh</arg>
            </entrypoint>
            <ports>
                <port>8080</port>
            </ports>
            <environment>
                <SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>ALWAYS</SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>
                <JHIPSTER_SLEEP>0</JHIPSTER_SLEEP>
            </environment>
            <useCurrentTimestamp>true</useCurrentTimestamp>
        </container>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

UPD.
After upgrading jib plugin to 1.61. and adding the docker:// before the image name, offline build is working, but I'm getting the below error at the output:

```
[INFO] --- jib-maven-plugin:1.6.1:dockerBuild (default-cli) @ mental ---
[WARNING] <container><useCurrentTimestamp> is deprecated; use <container><creationTime> with the value USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead
[WARNING] Setting image creation time to current time; your image may not be reproducible.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Containerizing application to Docker daemon as mental...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Container entrypoint set to [sh, -c, chmod +x /entrypoint.sh && sync && /entrypoint.sh]
[INFO] 
[INFO] Built image to Docker daemon as mental
[INFO] Executing tasks:
[INFO] [==============================] 100.0% complete
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  09:30 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-28T19:02:35+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "Thread-5" Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/RecursiveDeleteOption
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.filesystem.FileOperations.lambda$deleteRecursiveOnExit$1(FileOperations.java:102)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.RecursiveDeleteOption
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 2 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/RecursiveDeleteOption
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.filesystem.FileOperations.lambda$deleteRecursiveOnExit$1(FileOperations.java:102)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the config would help, but you can instruct jib via `<configuration>` to use local docker deamon as the source of the image by prepending the image name with `docker://` like below (which btw requires plugin version **1.6.0+**):

```
<configuration>
  <from>
    <image>docker://openjdk:alpine</image>
  </from>
  <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

HTH

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:1.4.0:dockerBuild (default-cli) on project mental: Invalid image reference docker://openjdk:alpine, perhaps you should check that the reference is formatted correctly according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description
[ERROR] For example, slash-separated name components cannot have uppercase letters: Invalid image reference: docker://openjdk:alpine
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Comment: I also pulled this image before I've started the build offline

Comment: and also, in my initial config I just had plugin configured 2 times, and the first onw had no configuration and the second one was configured well:

Comment: added to the main question text

Comment: can you up the version to latest? did you try `docker://adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot` ?

Comment: yes, I tried docker://adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot and got the same. Ok, thanks, will try with the latest plugin version.

Comment: The URL-style references were added to Jib 1.6.  Latest is release is 1.6.1.

Comment: sorry, I have realized that actually all the time I tired the last version I was still on 1.4 as I have changed the wrong variable in my pom.xml. So after I have fixed this, I got the docker image being built offline. Thanks for your help so much!

Comment: and only thin, that I'm getting exception printed to the output despite of build success